# Jobs scheduled through "Scheduler for PCF" fail with OutOfMemoryError

Tags: job-scheduling, cloud-foundry

I am pushing a batch application with 3g of memory configured,

```
applications:
- name: batch-app
memory: 3G
services:
    - scheduler
buildpack: java_buildpack
```

create a job for the batch application

```
cf create-job batch-app job-name ".java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"
```

and then schedule the job as follows:

```
cf schedule-job job-name "30 * ? * *"
```

Now every scheduled job execution fails with the following error:

```
2018-10-20 [APP/TASK/612f1b80] [OUT] Exit status 137 (out of memory)
```

The same job succeeds when it runs as a task (even with less memory than specified in the manifest):

```
cf run-task job-name ".java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher" --name "manual" -m 2GB
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is now possible. If you are using Scheduler version 1.2.33+, then the Scheduler API supports the ability to schedule jobs and define memory and disk limits for your scheduled tasks.

See the [Release Notes](https://docs.pivotal.io/scheduler/1-2/release-notes.html).

Please note that for Scheduler v1.2.33+ the API supports this capability but the corresponding version of the cf cli scheduler plugin does not. You need at least version 1.3 of the cf cli scheduler plugin to support changing these values through the cli.

You may download the latest cf cli plugin [from Tanzu Network here](https://network.pivotal.io/products/p-scheduler/#/releases/768937). Then install the plugin with `cf install-plugin -f path/to/download/scheduler-for-pcf-cliplugin-macosx64-binary-1.4.0-build.2`.

With the latest plugin installed, you can create your jobs and set the limits with the `--memory` and `--disk` flags.

For example:

```
cf create-job smallest-app say-hi 'echo "Hello World!"' --disk 512M --memory 128M
```

After that, you can run `cf run-job example` to see the enqueued job. You can also use `cf schedule-job` or `cf run-job` as you normally would.

---

I believe that the newer scheduler cf cli plugin should work with 1.2.33+ versions as well, but if you encounter issues. This process of using `curl` to send the request should still work.

This is the command to schedule a job as detailed at https://docs.pivotal.io/scheduler/1-2/api/#create-job:

```
curl -i -X POST https://scheduler.run.example.com/jobs?app_guid=$(cf app your-app --guid) \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H "Authorization: $(cf oauth-token)" \
  -d "{ \
      \"command\": \"echo 'hi'\", \
      \"disk_in_mb\": 1024, \
      \"memory_in_mb\": 1024, \
      \"name\": \"example\" \
     }"
```

Where `https://scheduler.run.example.com` is the location of your Scheduler. This breaks down to `https://scheduler.<system-domain>`, where `system-domain` is the domain under which your foundation has been installed.

If you run `cf api`, you'll see the API URL. The system domain is the part after `https://api.`.

For example:

```
$ cf api
api endpoint:   https://api.run.example.com
api version:    2.145.0
```

In this example "run.example.com" is my system domain, so `https://scheduler.run.example.com` would be my scheduler URL.

---

If you are using a version of Scheduler before 1.2.33, it is not possible. Older versions of Scheduler do not support having custom memory or disk settings. The scheduled job, unfortunately, does not use the app's memory limit either. It uses the default memory limit set on your foundation, like if you don't set a memory limit, which is usually 1G.

You can work around this in a couple of ways.

- You can increase the default memory limit for your platform. This obviously has the downside of impacting others on the platform that are relying on the default.
- You can push a web app that simply wraps your batch job. Then you can use the Scheduler's Call API to have scheduler call a URL on a given interval. https://docs.pivotal.io/pcf-scheduler/1-2/using-calls.html. This has the downside of being a little extra work.

You may also find these [API docs](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/) handy.

Comment: Supposedly supported by CLI as of [1.3](https://docs.pivotal.io/scheduler/1-3/release-notes.html)

Comment: How would I determine equivalent of `https://scheduler.run.pivotal.io/jobs` for my CF instance?

Comment: It'll be `https://scheduler.<your-system-domain>/jobs`. So if you go to `https://api.example.com` to login with the cf cli, then your system domain would be `example.com`.